remove reflection of some selected objects
I have a ground/floor object with reflective material. We can see all the reflection including the reflection of the environment map.

I want to mask out or exclude the env map dan the green donut from the reflection in the floor.
How can I do this ?

You have to use View Layers. You may want to watch/read some tutorials to get you started.
